# how to avoid XSS attack using css x:expression?

Tags: xss

I'm getting an alert in the page if I pass the following query string value in the URL

```
&67251"style%3d"x%3aexpression(alert(1))"c5c8316d7db=1
```

ex.

```
http://mysite.aspx?val1=2&&67251"style%3d"x%3aexpression(alert(1))"c5c8316d7db=1
```

I'm using componentart postback controls in my page, so it creates hidden variables in the page like below.

then second hidden variable is causing the alert. How can I avoid this? or how can I capture it and remove it before writing it to page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sanitize your variable before you output it on your page.

```
Response.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Request.QueryString["val1"]));
```

Comment: this query string value is injected into my http request, we dont what's the value will be in there. And this hidden variables are created by componentArt call back.